# SQL 2008 R2 Bi directional replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I'm looking for the right replication for my case:

I can't use P2P replication because one of my SQL's is Standard.
I have 2 SQL 2008 R2 and want to create a bi-directional replication.

What are my options?

Is a "always on" Merge replication functional?

Comment: Could you give a few more details of your goals?  EX: will each server modify the same record?  Are there 1000s of changes per hour? etc

Comment: the servers won't modify the same record at the same time, but will work on the same record. The changes are concentrated on one of the servers, only minimal access will be done on the other server, however there's a flow which makes them modify the same record, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to look into `SQL server transactional replication with immediately updating subscribers`.

Comment: aren't those replication types deprecated? is there another way?